# Ruby on Rails Migrating Databases Inconsistencies (Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training Chapter 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing the Lynda course and am up to migrating databases. So first it seems like there are some syntax differences between what is default in my newer version of Rails (3.2.6) than are in the video, but I took a look at the Ruby website and figured out that it likely doesn't matter.

However where I'm stuck is that when creating my `Users`Model that defines columns(attribs) to put things in, it creates it all, except that the ones I define myself (first name, last name, email and password) won't get created. Only the date created, date modified and ID do, I assume because they are the default ones and just work out of the box.

Here is the code the video tells you to use:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
      t.string "password", :limit => 40
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

I have put two asteriks around the differences below, the main one being a default that is `def up` in my version but in the video version it is `def self.up`. The other thing I noticed when I read the documentation on the Rails site was that instead of quotes you are supposed to use the `:`. Since the code as given by the video didn't work, I tried the code below as well. But I got the same result, with none of the `t.strings` actually being created in the table.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  **def up**
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string **:**first_name, :limit => 25
      t.string **:**last_name, :limit => 50
      t.string **:**email, :default => "", :null => false
      t.string **:**"password", :limit => 40
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  **def down**
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

So two questions:

1. Am I not using the proper syntax?
2. After the first time you 'set up' a table, if you do it again will it override the old configuration? Do I have to create a whole new database again? I'm not sure that by changing the 'users' file and rearranging the syntax, and then doing rake db:migrate that I can override what is there at all.

Thanks so much for your help.

-Dave

Comment: Did you do `rake db:migrate` before you run your rails server?

Answer (score 1):

Symbols versus strings shouldn't matter. Self.up versus up is the older style but also shouldn't matter. Rails tracks which migrations it has already run in the schema migrations table. A consequence of this is that once a migration has been run rails won't run it again, even if you have changed it.

You can do

```
rake db:rollback
```

To have rails run the down method for the last migration that was run (and so it will be run again when you next run `db:migrate`)

It can be more appropriate to create a new migration to add extra columns - if you have already pushed the original migration to your repository I would usually do this